# ES6 AngularJS 1 $inject Inheritence

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have 3 child controllers extending a single parent controller like so:

```
class ParentController {
    constructor( $scope, $state ){
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$state = $state;
    }
}
ParentController.$inject = [ '$scope', '$state' ];

// CHILD A
class ChildAController extends ParentController {
    constructor( $scope, $state, AService ){
        super( $scope, $state );

        this.AService = AService;
    }
    // ... common functions
}
ChildAController.$inject.push( 'AService' );

// CHILD B
class ChildBController extends ParentController {
    constructor( $scope, $state, BService ){
        super( $scope, $state );

        this.BService = BService;
    }
}
ChildBController.$inject.push( 'BService' );
```

My issue is that there is a reference kept with the `$inject` array.  Meaning that ChildB's 3rd dependency is `AService` instead of `BService`.

So all children have the same following inject array

```
$inject => [ '$scope', '$state', 'AService', 'BService' ]
```

Instead of their own.

Is there a nice way around this? Or will I have to create a sort of provider service to decide which Service to pass on?

They're all going to be doing the exact same task but with data from a different service, so I'd like to try any keep this inheritance structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a copy in the child controllers?

```
ChildAController.$inject = [...ParentController.$inject, 'AService'];

ChildBController.$inject = [...ParentController.$inject, 'BService'];
```

Comment: Well I've just learn't about those three dots, so bonus. Thanks!